# Attribute error when trying to use pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to run the pyinstaller and I am keep getting an error

```
if compat.is_py312:
AttributeError: module 'PyInstaller.compat' has no attribute 'is_py312'
```

I couldn't find any answers online for this particular problem, anyone has any idea how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem. Are you using Anaconda?

Comment: Did you managed to solve it?